# I can't transfer cell label text to UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a bit of trouble with setting my tableviewcell's label text to another viewcontroller's `UILabel`.

My code is as follow:

```
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:nil)
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailVC")as! DetailVC
    viewController.comText = currentCell.labelName.text
    present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: From which method you execute the above code? What value does `viewController.comText` contains when you output the value to log?

Comment: What does crash log says if any error?

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Not related but don't get data from the cell (view), get it from the data source (model)

Comment: please can you post your viewcontrollers interfaces? where is comText declared?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Error:- Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'UILabel!'

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic `public class DetailVC : UIViewController {  @IBOutlet public weak var comText: UILabel! }`

Comment: ok .. then if comtext is a label.. i am right.. check the answer i provided pls

Comment: @yashrathod problem resolved?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Not Yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that you are trying to access the view when it has not been created yet:

> This code will create a view controller

```
var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailVC")as! DetailVC
```

> Here you are trying to set the label text before presenting your
>   controller.

```
viewController.comText = currentCell.labelName.text
```

**At this point the controller has not loaded its view yet**. As there is no view, there is no label. What you should do is **set a String property in you destinationViewController** and set it here. Then in the `ViewDidLoad()` method of your destinationViewController **set the label text to be the String referenced in the property**.

> This code presents the viewcontroller and tell it it should load its view

```
present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> Here is a picture of the life cycle of a view controller

You can only work with the view when it has triggered the ViewDidLoad() method
[image]

Comment: According to this line: `viewController.comText = currentCell.labelName.text` `comText` is already a String property (else XCode should be at least throwing a warning, and maybe crashing). The question is when `comText` is read to set the value to the target label.

Comment: We cannot be sure if it is a String or a Label.. I already posted a comment but he havent replied

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion (if Massimo's suggestion didn't work), try adding the following line after creating your view controller:

```
_ = viewController.view!
```

The "bang" might not be needed (I don't have my Xcode open at the moment), but this will cause the viewDidLoad to execute, thus "inflating" your view and its related widgets that were declared/defined in your storyboard.  Then, you can assign any text you wish to your targeted UILabel.text property.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's so trivial but your `comText` is actually a `UILabel`?
Because if so you have to set the `text` properties not the entire object:

```
viewController.comText = currentCell.labelName.text
```

should be so

```
viewController.comText.text = currentCell.labelName.text
```